# Putting arduino to sleep due to depleting battery power

Tags: arduino, power-management

I have built a data-logging functionality using sd card and ds-1307. T continuously record temperature data. However since this functionality is powered by battery, I intend to monitor for the battery power and put the circuit to sleep for an extended time frame. During this mode I would like to disable the data-logging and rtc module from drawing power just like arduino. This sleep mode could for a day or a month until a battery is replaced. How to achieve this programatically?

Comment: The ds1307 doesn't have a sleep more - but it consumes very little current when in battery backup mode. Is this how you are using it? What kind of Arduino are you using? You say "..drawing power just like arduino.." does this mean you have already figured how to put the Arduino to sleep?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using an arduino uno r3 and have put it to sleep for 8 seconds using WDT. However I need to make this sleep for a longer time in the SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN. Need help in shutting off data-logging for more than this so that the battery life can extend until replaced.

Answer (score 0):

The simple code example on this UNO base data logger:

[An Arduino UNO based Datalogger for the Classroom](http://edwardmallon.wordpress.com/2015/12/22/arduino-uno-based-data-logger-with-no-soldering/)

Puts the logger to sleep with Rocket Screems low power library, and then wakes the logger with the alarm signal from the DS3231 RTC - but the same library works with the 1307. This lets you modify the time from 1-59 minutes.

Monitoring the battery voltage to put the unit to sleep is a bit trickier, as you need to use a voltage divider so that the signal can be read on one of the Arduinos analog pins. I usually use two 4.7M ohm resistors for this, effectively cutting the power supply voltage in half so it is safely below the Arduino's operating voltage.